# Light Weight Python Web FrameWork

Tags: python, html

I have a database that can be fetched using mysql query and send the data as response for an ajax jquery request. Which python framework would be best suitable to satisfy this primary need?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Django, Flask, framework-du-jour.

Comment: Bottle and Cherrypy are also pretty light weight.

Comment: I would say that if you want a lightweight framework, you should try flask or bottle. Django or web2py might include a lot of other tools that you might not use.

Comment: Pyramid. Always Pyramid.

Comment: You see why this kind of question is off-topic!?

Comment: Off topic: Consider Go Lang, it is very lightweight language with some web stacks. Ultra fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask. Just use Flask.

Honestly you'll finish your project in 20 minutes.